# VSCode webview panel file link

Tags: visual-studio-code

For my extension in VSCode I have a html document with a file link in the html.   It appears blue and underlined in the webviewpanel, but when I click on it, nothing happens.  Is there a way to click on the hyperlink and make it load the document?

Comment: use `ctrl + click`

Comment: ctrl + click doesn't work in the webviewpanel.  ctrl + click works if the link is an editor or terminal

Answer (score 0):

It is harder because of security reasons to link to a local resource in a webviewPanel.  I found a work around solution to link to a command that opens a file in the html.